# onEdit specific cell -copy content from one sheet to another

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I found this script online that is working like a charm however i would like to trigger it when I change cell E3 in sheet YYY, worksheet 'database'.

I would like to import the data from one spreadsheet to another when I edit a specific cell in the destination spreadsheet.

I am new at this so any help much appreciated.

```
var sourceSpreadsheetID = "XXX";
var sourceWorksheetName = "sold-for-sale";
var targetSpreadsheetID = "YYY";
var targetWorksheetName = "database";

function importData() {
  var thisSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sourceSpreadsheetID);
  var thisWorksheet = thisSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(sourceWorksheetName);
  var thisData = thisWorksheet.getDataRange();
  //Uncomment line 11 below and comment out line 9 if you want to sync a named range. Replace "teamBugs" with your named range.
  //var thisData = thisSpreadsheet.getRangeByName("teamBugs");

  var toSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(targetSpreadsheetID);
  var toWorksheet = toSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(targetWorksheetName);
  var toRange = toWorksheet.getRange(1, 1, thisData.getNumRows(), thisData.getNumColumns())
  toRange.setValues(thisData.getValues()); 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to update the destination spreadsheet (`YYY`) when a certain cell in this spreadsheet is edited.

To achieve that, you have to do two things:

#### Install onEdit trigger:

Install an [onEdit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) trigger that executes `importData` when editions are made to `YYY`. A [simple trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) won't be enough, since you are trying to access several spreadsheets, an action that will require authorization, and simple triggers cannot access services that require authorization (see [Restrictions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#restrictions)).

You can install this trigger [programmatically](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_programmatically), by executing this function once (see [ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/spreadsheet-trigger-builder#onEdit())):

```js
function createOnEditTrigger() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(targetSpreadsheetID);
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("importData")
    .forSpreadsheet(ss)
    .onEdit()
    .create();
}
```

#### Check edited cell:

After installing the trigger, `importData` will fire every time `YYY` is edited, disregarding which cell was edited. To restrict that, you could check which cell was edited at the beginning of `importData`.

You can use the [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) for this: the [onEdit event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit) has the property `range`, which refers to the [Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range) of cells that was edited. You can use [getA1Notation()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getA1Notation()) to retrieve the A1 notation of this edited range, and check if it matches your desired one.

For example, if you wanted to listen to changes to `A5`, you would do this:

```js
function importData(e) {
  if (e.range.getA1Notation() === "A5") {
    // Previous importData code
  }
}
```

#### Reference:

- [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)

Comment: Thanks @Iamblichus, the first part is working great, however when I am trying to install the second part I get stuck and nothing happens. I am putting my function in the importData function and the vars ontop as it was before, is this right?

Comment: @MeeWennman The vars can be outside the function, but the code related to `importData` should be inside the function `importData(e)` I wrote, after the `if` condition. It's important to note that this will only run if `A5` is the edited cell (you should change that according to your preferences). Also you can click `Edit > Current project's triggers` to check that you have installed the `onEdit` trigger.